# Custom list definition

Tags: list, haskell

given (from Haskell Amuse Bouche Lectures)

```
module Part2a where

    data List α = EndOfList
                | Link α (List α)
        deriving Show   -- makes printing out results possible
```

Usage Examples:

```
empty = EndOfList
oneWord = Link "apple" EndOfList
twoWords = Link "banana" (Link "cantaloupe" EndOfList)
```

Question:
 Where is the "Link" function is defined?

I searched everywhere and could not find it.

Answer (score 8):

`Link` is the second constructor of your `List a` type. It is defined here:

```hs
data List α = EndOfList
            | Link α (List α) -- this line defines the Link constructor
```

It is used in your second code snippet to create values of type `List String`.